# Difference between Set and List for DynamoDB

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb

I'm uploading data to my Dynamo Db table with the sensor's data. I created a List for sensors locations, however, I heard that it might be better to create a set and I could not find a difference between the way I upload data and the way it would be presented. Currently if I use List("L":) I have [ { "S" : "Culpeper VA" }, { "S" : "Colorado Springs Co" } ] in my table. Would it be different if I use Set instead and what attribute on the left I would use instead of "L" for list?

```
 {
                    "Sensor" : {
                        "S": "Sensor1"
                    },
                    "SensorDescription": {
                        "S" : "Sensor to meassure water temperature"
                    },
                    "ImageFile" : {
                        "S" : "/Sensors/images/acoustic-elementarray.jpg"
                    },
                    
                    "SampleRate":{
                        "N" : "2048"
                    },
                    "Locations" : {
                        
                        "L": [
                            {
                                "S" : "Culpeper VA"
                            },
                            {
                                "S": "Colorado Springs Co"
                            }
                            ]
                    }

                }
```

That is my JSON that I use with put item API call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I figured out, the best way in my case would be to use String Set instead, update JSON is :

```
"Locations" : {

    "SS": [ "Colorado Springs Co" , "Culpeper VA"
    ]
}
```